# Regex for google search

Tags: regex-greedy

I am looking to capture Google search terms from logs. I have different users using different browsers that create different URLs that I would like to pull from. Below are two payload examples. My thoughts are grab between the `=` and the `&` in the URL string.

I want to capture: `Please let this work`

- `(?==).*?(?=&)` - Matches from the `&` after the word `work` up to the first `=`
- `q\\=(.+?)&` will only work on the first example and misses the second.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? Or what I may be doing wrong?

**Example one**:

```
<159>Oct 15 11:00:30 10.100.67.245 LEEF:1.0|Websense|Security|7.8.3|transaction:permitted|sev=1 cat=76  usrName=LDAP://10.10.66.137 OU=test,OU=fake,OU=fake,DC=Main,DC=com/Jane Doe src=10.10.3.50  srcPort=56725   srcBytes=687    dstBytes=68244  dst=173.194.121.51  dstPort=443 proxyStatus-code=200    serverStatus-code=200   duration=0  method=GET  disposition=1026    contentType=text/html; charset\=UTF-8   reason=-    policy=Super Administrator**Travel  role=8  userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko url=https://www.google.com/search?q\=Please+Let+this+work&sourceid\=ie7&rls\=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie\=&oe\=&rlz\=&safe\=active&gws_rd\=ssl
```

**Example two:**

```
<159>Oct 15 11:00:30 10.100.66.245 LEEF:1.0|Websense|Security|7.8.3|transaction:permitted|sev=1 cat=76  usrName=LDAP://10.10.67.137 OU=test,OU=fake,OU=ccgh,DC=fake,DC=com/Jane Doe src=10.10.3.50  srcPort=56725   srcBytes=687    dstBytes=68244  dst=173.194.121.51  dstPort=443 proxyStatus-code=200    serverStatus-code=200   duration=0  method=GET  disposition=1026    contentType=text/html; charset\=UTF-8   reason=-    policy=Super Administrator**Travel  role=8  userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko url=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Please+let+this+work&safe=active
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative character group `([^&]+)` to match everything between the `q=` and the next `&`. Complicating the matter is that there can be optional `\` before the equal sign: `q\=a+search+term`.

Try this

```
q(?:\\)?=([^&]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vS5qB3/1)